# what is the most efficient way to found the same element between two vector

Tags: c++

say if i have to character vector like below

```
vector<char> sv;
sv.push_back('a');
sv.push_back('b');
sv.push_back('c');
sv.push_back('d');
sv.push_back('e');
```

then i have a other character vector which have partial element that sv has include before

```
vector<char> sv2;
v2.push_back('c');
v2.push_back('d');
v2.push_back('a');
v2.push_back('f');
v2.push_back('g');
```

if i want to count the times same element that have appear, what is the best way to solve this?

Comment: Are the vectors sorted?

Comment: sorting and std::set_intersection.

Comment: Consider if it is unsorted

Comment: If you cannot modify `sv` and `sv2`, create sorted copies. You can also try the linear-complexity method and benchmark the two.

Answer (score 0):

For `vector<char>` it can be done in linear time. Let's assume for simplicity that `char`'s are unsigned, or that we use `vector<unsigned char>`.

```
int s[256] = { 0 }, s2[256] = { 0 };
for (auto a : sv)
   ++s[a];
for (auto a : sv2)
    ++s2[a];
int count = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < 256; ++i)
    count += min(s[i], s2[i]);
```

In the general case use sorting and `set_intersection`, as **@Jarod42** suggested.